# Broken Packages Fix Problem (For Wine)

Tags: package-management, wine, playonlinux

I was trying to install Heroes of Might and Magic 3 with Play on Linux. When I start the program it gives me an error message

> PlayOnLinux cannot find wine (from Wine). You should install it to use PlayOnLinux.

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

I tried this but I got an error message:

> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

What should I do?

---

Input:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package wine is a virtual package provided by:
  winehq-staging 4.0~rc1~cosmic
  winehq-stable 3.0.4~cosmic
  winehq-devel 4.0~rc1~cosmic
  wine-development 3.6-1
You should explicitly select one to install.
E: Package 'wine' has no installation candidate
```

And when I type:

```
sudo apt-get install winehq-stable
```

I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 3.0.4~cosmic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here is my system:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-38 linux-headers-4.15.0-38-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-38-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-38-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-38-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
$ sudo apt remove wine winehq-stable

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Virtual packages like 'wine' can't be removed
Package 'winehq-stable' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
   linux-headers-4.15.0-38 linux-headers-4.15.0-38-generic  
   linux-image-4.15.0-38-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-38-generic  
   linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-38-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
```

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading
>
> state information... Done The following packages will be REMOVED:
>
> linux-headers-4.15.0-38 linux-headers-4.15.0-38-generic
>
> linux-image-4.15.0-38-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-38-generic
>
> linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-38-generic 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5
>
> to remove and 0 not upgraded. After this operation, 336 MB disk space
>
> will be freed. Do you want to continue? [Y/n]  (Reading database ...
>
> 268454 files and directories currently installed.) Removing
>
> linux-headers-4.15.0-38-generic (4.15.0-38.41) ... Removing
>
> linux-headers-4.15.0-38 (4.15.0-38.41) ... Removing
>
> linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-38-generic (4.15.0-38.41) ... Removing
>
> linux-image-4.15.0-38-generic (4.15.0-38.41) ...
>
> /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools: update-initramfs: Deleting
>
> /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-38-generic
>
> /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub: Generating grub configuration
>
> file ... Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-42-generic Found
>
> initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-42-generic Found linux image:
>
> /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-39-generic Found initrd image:
>
> /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-39-generic Adding boot menu entry for EFI
>
> firmware configuration done Removing linux-modules-4.15.0-38-generic
>
> (4.15.0-38.41) ...

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove 'deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
```

Has no output.

```
sudo apt update
```

> > Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]     Ign:2
>
> https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/Ubuntu_18.10_standard
>
> ./ InRelease Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>
> bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [204 B] Hit:4
>
> https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian
>   /Ubuntu_18.10_standard
>
> ./ Release Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>
> bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [14.5 kB] Get:7
>
> http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11
>
> 48x48 Icons [9,088 B] Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>
> bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [36.7 kB] Get:9
>
> http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11
>
> 128x128 Icons [65.9 kB] Hit:10 http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>
> bionic InRelease                     Get:11
>
> http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
>
> Get:12 http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
>
> [74.6 kB] Get:13 http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>
> bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [402 kB] Get:14
>
> http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
>
> [459 kB] Hit:15 http://deb.playonlinux.com xenial InRelease
>
> Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu
>
> bionic InRelease Get:17 http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>
> bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [245 kB] Hit:18
>
> http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>
> Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu bionic
>
> InRelease   Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu
>
> bionic InRelease         Get:21 http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>
> bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [55.7 kB] Hit:22
>
> http://ppa.launchpad.net/rikmills/latte-dock/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>
> Get:23 http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11
>
> 64x64 Icons [105 kB] Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/vcmi/ppa/ubuntu
>
> bionic InRelease                Hit:25
>
> http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>
> Get:26 http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11
>
> 128x128 Icons [266 kB] Err:27
>
> http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu bionic
>
> Release   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80] Err:28
>
> http://ppa.launchpad.net/vcmi/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
>
> 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80] Get:29
>
> http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64
>
> Packages [594 kB] Get:30 http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>
> bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [588 kB] Get:31
>
> http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64
>
> DEP-11 Metadata [199 kB] Get:32 http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>
> bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [186 kB] Get:33
>
> http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11
>
> 64x64 Icons [333 kB] Get:34 http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>
> bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 128x128 Icons [767 kB] Get:35
>
> http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64
>
> DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B] Get:36 http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>
> bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,812 B] Reading
>
> package lists... Done
>
> E: The repository
>
> 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu bionic
>
> Release' does not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a
>
> repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
>
> default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
>
> configuration details. E: The repository
>
> 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/vcmi/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not
>
> have a Release file. N: Updating from such a repository can't be done
>
> securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See apt-secure(8)
>
> manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>
> state information... Done Calculating upgrade... Done 0 upgraded, 0
>
> newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

```
sudo apt-get install winehq-stable
```

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>
> state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This
>
> may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
>
> using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
>
> yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
>
> information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  winehq-stable :
>
> Depends: wine-stable (= 3.0.4~cosmic) E: Unable to correct problems,
>
> you have held broken packages.

Edit:

```
 sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
```

> Hit:1 http://deb.playonlinux.com xenial InRelease 
>   Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu
>   bionic
>   InRelease Hit:3 http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>   Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
>   Hit:5 http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
>   Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>   Hit:7 http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
>   Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu bionic
>   InRelease    Hit:9 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic
>   InRelease                 Hit:10
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>   Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rikmills/latte-dock/ubuntu bionic
>   InRelease    Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/vcmi/ppa/ubuntu bionic
>   InRelease                Hit:13
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>   Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu
>   bionic Release   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80] Err:15
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/vcmi/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release   404  Not
>   Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80] Reading package lists... Done E: The
>   repository
>   'http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu bionic
>   Release' does not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a
>   repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
>   default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
>   configuration details. E: The repository
>   'http://ppa.launchpad.net/vcmi/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not
>   have a Release file. N: Updating from such a repository can't be done
>   securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See apt-secure(8)
>   manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: @user535733 I did it.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is 'Bionic'. The packages you are adding are labelled 'Cosmic' (18.10). See the problem?

Comment: Yeah I see the problem. I just don't know the solution. Which is the reason why I write here.

Comment: One easy solution is to uninstall all the non-Ubuntu Wine packages, then disable that non-Ubuntu Wine repository, and simply use wine-stable 3.0-1 that's *already* in the 14.04 Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: I don't know how to do those things and I'm kinda afraid damaging it more. I simply uninstalled wine and installed it again and it didn't helped me at all. What now?

Comment: "How do I do that?" is a *learning* question. You must learn the skills to remove the software you added. How you remove it depends upon how you installed it. There is no single magic incantation. Since I have not seen whatever instructions you followed, I don't know how you installed it. Please edit your question to clearly explain (or link) the instructions you followed. Also, please be clear about *which part* you don't understand how to do.

Comment: I usually use purge when I want to remove a program. But I don't know if that removes packages as well. Yes, I need to learn those thing and I am learning it right now. But the learning process takes some time since I'm not familiar neither with Ubuntu nor any of other distribution in Linux and the logic of them. So you can be sure that I don't want any "magical" code from you. Anyway, thank you for your effort and time. https://linuxconfig.org/install-wine-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux this is the instructions I followed for the installation. Do you need any more information?

Comment: The basic theory is to follow the instructions in reverse: `sudo apt remove wine winehq-stable` and anything else you added. Then  `sudo apt autoremove` to remove dependencies. Then  `sudo apt-add-repository --remove 'deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'`...assuming that's what you added. Then `sudo apt update` because you just changed your repositories.  Then `sudo apt upgrade` to test that your package system is working again and all the damage has been fixed.  Then, and only then, are you ready to install wine.

Comment: I added the commands I used and the outpost to the post as new edit. Still have the same error I'm afraid. Is there a way to uninstall all the non-bionic packages and if yes would that be a good idea?

Comment: 1) When you are following steps, and you get an error, STOP. Do not go on to the next step. You had errors with `apt update`, but still tried to keep going...bad idea. Look up how to fix your (unrelated) PPA errors. 2) Adding lots of PPAs is a *bad idea* for unskilled users - they are untested and unsupported and can break your system *like the Wine PPA already did*. If the package is already in the Ubuntu repositories (many are), consider using those instead. 3) Read your output - you still have the `wine-stable` package installed (or marked for install). Remove it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: I had to look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190465/winehq-on-ubuntu-19-10 and https://www.reddit.com/r/winehq/comments/9t7k54/cannot_meet_dependencies_on_64_bit_ubuntu_18041/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do 1:

```
 sudo apt-add-repository --remove 'deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/Ubuntu_18.10_standard ./'
```

Do 2:

```
 wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key

 sudo apt-key add Release.key

 sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
```

3:sudo apt-get update

4:Then install your preferred wine

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable

sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel

sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

Hope it works!

Comment: It did NOT work.

Comment: My output: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 4.0~xenial)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: No it doesn't work

Comment: Nope. Just same error: "The following packages have unmet dependencies: winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 4.13~buster) E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Comment: @Boann can you do sudo apt update and send me the output

Comment: update output @AashifProXD
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease [97.5 kB]
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:3 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Get:5 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease [97.5 kB]
Get:6 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease [88.8 kB]
Fetched 284 kB in 1s (245 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building tree
Reading information... Done
All packages are up to date.

Comment: @mmdts Remove all wine repositories using the software and updates tool in Ubuntu

Comment: Then after follow the guide in https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu for Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Did, it still expects me to install dependencies one at a time (otherwise gives me this broken packages message), and some of those i386 dependencies break existing packages (including mpv, ffmpeg, gnome-desktop, among others), setting them for removal.

Comment: Its not working!!

Wasted my 10 minsSSSSSSSSS!!

Comment: winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~bionic)

Comment: this seems to the issue https://askubuntu.com/a/1205535/414411

Comment: also didnot work for me(ubuntu 20.4)! its useless

Answer (score 41):

The problem is that Wine now depends on libfaudio0, but Ubuntu versions prior to 19.10 don't include it in the standard repositories.

The link to the Winehq forum page with directions on how to install the packages is: https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=32192.

For Ubuntu 18.04 do:

```
wget https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/amd64/libfaudio0_19.07-0~bionic_amd64.deb
wget https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/i386/libfaudio0_19.07-0~bionic_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libfaudio0_19.07-0~bionic_amd64.deb libfaudio0_19.07-0~bionic_i386.deb
```

Then you should be able to update and upgrade as you would normally.

Comment: so stupid i wish they updated the install instructions to include this current state, at the very least put "apt" rather than "apt-get" :/

Comment: Why did it take so long to find this?

Comment: This! Thank you :) Worked for me on 18.04: `sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/ ./'`, `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DFA175A75104960E`, `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`.

Comment: consider adding the directions in the answer as well

Comment: can't install it on 16.04 Ubuntu, `dpkg: error processing package libfaudio0:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libfaudio0:i386:
 libfaudio0:i386 depends on libsdl2-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.8).
`

Comment: I had to do this, then got an error and was prompted to do `apt --fix-broken install`. Afterward, wine installed successfully.

Comment: I confirm that this it works. Beginning with Wine 4.5, both Wine Stable and Wine Development require amd64 and i386 versions of libfaudio0, but libfaudio0 is not available from the repository. Therefore, libfaudio0 must be downloaded and installed manually.

Answer (score 17):

late answer

I had a similar problem:
What I did:

I remove all "wine" ppa using "Software and updates" tool in ubuntu / kubuntu. Then, i followed the guide here: [install latest wine](https://itsfoss.com/install-latest-wine/)  or  [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu).

In my case, i added

`sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main'`

and no other repository. Then...

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Sincerely,
Elias Tsolis

Comment: This worked for me on linux mint 19.1

Comment: Didn't work on Ubuntu 16.04, same error as above: `winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~xenial)`

Answer (score 1):

From the error you're getting, looks like you have configured the `whinehq` repository.

As the very same error is telling you, you have to choose *which branch* of `wine` you'd like to install, as `wine` is just a **virtual package** and it has no installation candidates so `apt` cannot choose by itself what to install.

As [indicated here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu), you can install a *stable* version (`winehq-stable`), a *development* version (`winehq-devel`) or a *staging* version (`winehq-staging`).

While I'm pretty happy on my systems with `winehq-staging`, I suggest you install the `winehq-stable` branch that (as the name implies) should be the "most stable" branch of `wine`.

As suggested on the official WineHQ documentation, make sure to install it with the flag `--install-recommends`

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 3.0.4~cosmic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

This is what I get

Comment: @sarp I've updated my answer. Make sure you use `--install-recommends`.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and time but I still have the same error:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 3.0.4~cosmic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @sarp If you're still getting errors, try `sudo apt  --fix-broken install`. Please don't post errors in comments, edit instead your answer with the results of the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try adding an SDL2 backport. This is especially useful to users that need to fill in dependencies that repeatedly nag you when you try to add them in. I recently found this online. The command is then followed by the package list update and then your desired choice of Wine. I tested this on Ubuntu 18.04. Specifically, Zorin OS 15. Upvote if this resolved your problem. :)

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get --install-recommends winehq-stable`

`sudo apt-get --install-recommends winehq-devel`

`sudo apt-get --install-recommends winehq-staging`

Comment: Zorin is off topic. Please post answers tested on Ubuntu.

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.4, this was the fix for me.