# WineHQ on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: wine, ppa, 19.10, winetricks

I have been following wine's steps to install `winehq`, but despite I've seem to be done all I can, I keep getting this error:

```
The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

If anybody could shed a light as to where I should go from here, I'd appreciate it.
Thanks.

Here is the updated output, after I've tried the suggestions below:

```
antonio@mclinux:~$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
antonio@mclinux:~$ wget -nc -qO- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -
OK
antonio@mclinux:~$ sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main'
Hit:1 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ricotz/unstable/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:3 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease    
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease                                
Hit:5 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease                             
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan InRelease                          
Hit:7 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan InRelease            
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan Release      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Could you help me see what's going on?

Cheers,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`does not have a release file` indicate the repository has no support for your Ubuntu release, in this case it's Ubuntu Eoan → 19.10.

You have added deprecated/outdated repository, the developer has put up an announcement regarding this issue on the WineHQ mailing list https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2017-March/117104.html.

You have to follow the new guide for installing Wine, luckily the Wine team has made this easy by posting a complete guide on their [site](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)— which you can uses with your 19.10.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
wget -nc -qO- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main'
```

Then install the packages.

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

<sub>According to https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/eoan/main/binary-amd64/, the only available version is: `staging` and `devel`</sub>

---

#### UPDATE

The new repo works fine, it's just you haven't removed old obsolete repo which you added before.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:wine/wine-builds
sudo apt update
```

Now there should not be any error.

Comment: Thanks, @Jim. I'll look into that once I get back home. Cheers!

Comment: @AntonioSantos I have edited my post, kindly check it.

Comment: Boooom! It worked! Thanks a for your patience!

Comment: No problem, glad your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 4):

**My solution for 19.10;**
(It's worked for me on Ubuntu 19.10)

Don't use this repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main'
```

Use this repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/bionic main'
```

"eoan main" is recommented by winehq official website but not works. If you trying using 19.04 repository on 19.10, its works fine :)

**If you want to use WineHQ for 19.10, enter this commands;**

(Switch to "root" user.)

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
rm -rf winehq.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

For testing, enter this command:

```
winecfg
```

Comment: Thanks! Got it to work based on the previous answer, though! I tried voting it up, but I don't have enough reputation to do so. Cheers.

Comment: Hasan Merkit's solution worked for me on Lubuntu 19.01. When I tested with 'winecfg,' errors came up about 'Wine Mono Installer,' then 'Wine Geko Installer'. Both errors presented a GUI to correct the issues. After clicking to run the GUIs Wine works. Winecfg runs without error now. I downloaded Windows Notepad and it runs fine on my Lubuntu (Light Ubuntu) laptop.