# Error when installing Wine on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, wine, winetricks, held-packages

When I am installing Wine on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~xenial)
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Broken Packages Fix Problem (For Wine)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100351/broken-packages-fix-problem-for-wine)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install wine on ubuntu (actually lubuntu) 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04)