# Installing wine and photoshop in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wine, photoshop

To install Photoshop in Ubuntu 18.04, I've been attempting to install Wine.

I got following error:

> You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. The
> following packages have unmet dependencies:  libpython3.7-stdlib :
> Depends: libpython3.7-minimal (= 3.7.13-1+bionic1) but
> 3.7.13-1+bionic3 is to be installed  python3.7 : Depends: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.13-1+bionic3) but 3.7.13-1+bionic1 is to be
> installed  winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.1~bionic-1) E:
> Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages
> (or specify a solution).

[image]

How to solve the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1231279/612958) on [that page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100351/broken-packages-fix-problem-for-wine/1231279#1231279)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport

sudo apt-get update
```

Then install one wine type, or [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1205535/612958) that will get the missing files, working on ubuntu 18.04.